# Is it possible to improve the performance of a pretrained TensorFlow model?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I've been looking around the internet for a while, and can't seem to find what I'm after. I want to take a pre-trained object detection model, like one from [TensorFlow's object detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md), and improve its performance on certain classes, for instance chairs.

My attempts at doing this have involved taking a model trained on the coco dataset and training it on pictures of chairs that I compiled. However, this resulted in the model forgetting most of what it already knew, and become only good at recognizing chairs. I want the model to retain its performance on all classes I don't touch, and get better at the ones I want it to. Does anybody have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: what is the point of doing this? Image if you can remain the model's performance of previous classes and improve its performance of one particular class, then we can do the same for all other classes as well, then the whole model's performance can be improved, which would have been provided as a better pretrained model. So your idea does not seem to make sense.

Comment: @danyfang so are you saying that this isn't possible? Can you link to a documented reason somewhere I can read about?